# TypeError: UserCreateForm() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to **django** and I am developing a social media site **following the course** and I am facing this **weird error** when I try to open signup page from the site, which after a lot of search and experiments wasn't able to get away with.Thus, I came here so if anyone could help me.

**My forms.py file where i think the actual culprit is**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

  class Meta:
      fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
      model = get_user_model()

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['username'].label = 'Username'
      self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
```

**views.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from . import forms


# Create your views here.
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
```

**urls.py file in the application directory i.e. accounts/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from . import views

#code here
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='signin.html'), name='login'),
    re_path(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    re_path(r'^signup/$', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```

**full log of error I am facing**

```
File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\envs\pyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 133, in get
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\envs\pyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 66, in get_context_
data
    kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()
  File "C:\Users\dell\Anaconda3\envs\pyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 33, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
TypeError: UserCreateForm() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'
[31/May/2020 12:51:46] "GET /accounts/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 500 90675
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as this, and for the same reason: You declared your form improperly.

This:

```
def UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
```

Should be this:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
```